# C++11 includes std::stoi, why not std::itos?

Tags: c++, parsing, strings, c++11

I noticed to my glee that C++11 has a [`std::sto@`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) family of functions for easily unpacking ints/floats/longs whatever from strings. I'm surprised however, that the opposite isn't implemented. Why didn't the standards committee include a `std::itos` family of functions for going from ints/floats/whatever (back) to strings?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I was mistaken, there is a set of "Xtos" functions, they are all just named `to_string`. Each to_string is overloaded to take a different basic type, i.e.:

```
std::string to_string(float f);
std::string to_string(int f);
...
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065413/stdlexical-cast-is-there-such-a-thing) for more info.

Comment: Which leaves the question why the `stoX` functions were named such awkwardly instead of providing a matching generic `from_string<T>` specialized for each arithmetic type `T`.

Comment: Probably following on from C

Comment: to_string is not the exact opposite of stoi, bacause in stoi() you can specify base, but in to_string() you cant :/